# Can someone please tell me the problem with this css class?

Tags: css

I am learning about outlines and wanted to do an example for my testing site thingy. For some strange reason, it doesn't work. I've analyzed it for a while and can't seem to find anything wrong, and even tried some small changes to no prevail. I don't know if my issue is a lack of knowledge about CSS or if there is some error when loading, all I know is that it's not working.

```css
.outlinered{
    border-color: blue;
    outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="outlinered">This has red outline and blue border.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only setting the colors, you should set the border and outline style too:

```
.outlinered {
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    outline-color: red;
    outline-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: I cant accept it yet but i will when I get the chance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a red outline, unless you mean like a red background?

You also haven't specified a border density, that is to say, how thick the border should be or it's style - that is why you can't see your blue border.

What you are looking for *might* be;

```css
.outlinered {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="outlinered">This has red outline and blue border.</p>
```

Unless you mean you're looking to add Stroke to your text?

Then [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) might be what you are after. Just note that not all browsers will support it, particularly IE11; unless that doesn't matter.

**EDIT:** I think @ray-caballero solution answers your question. I'm silly and didn't think about the outline property... d'oh.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this may help you ..**

You have to give **`border-style`** and **`outline-style`** also.

```css
.outlinered {
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    outline-color: red;
    outline-style: solid;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="outlinered">This has red outline and blue border.</p>
```